How to upload all folders, subfolders and files from file explorer to SharePoint library using PowerAutomate?
How to upload all folders, subfolders and files from file explorer to SharePoint library using PowerAutomate?
How i can upload all folders, subfolders and files from file explorer to SharePoint library using PowerAutomate? I am able to get files in a folder but dont know how i can traverse each subfolder and look for a file till last.

Which File Explorer? Local PC or other? Update your question with more details. Usually it would be easier just to upload the parent folder and not worry about each and every file nested within.

Yes i want to upload the files from one server's file system so that it remains in sync with SharePoint library

Simple suggestion, use One Drive to sync.

As it was suggested before, I would user OneDrive for this task:

make your DocumentList list sync with your OneDrive account 


find the synced folder in your OneDrive local folder
Copy/Move everything to here. After syncing, every files, folders, subfolders will be in the SPO Documents list as well, where you can use the default Sharepoint search features.


I tried this and it is working fine. But the folder with organization name that has been auto setup on server is showing up inside C drive. Will that still be taking up server's space even if it is synced to SharePoint?

yes, by design, because you synced it, and didn't move it. If you would like to free the server's space, you can disconnect the local folder (or move it to an other folder) (= it is the backup now). After breaking the sync, you can delete the original folders.
